# Italic text in Steam under Wine

Tags: wine, fonts, steam

Running steam using wine.  Works perfectly except for a small error:

[image: steam wine screenshot]

All my text is italic for some reason.

I'm using the latest wine release 1.3.12 and Ubuntu 10.10

Thought I'd try here first, if this would be more appropriate in a more wine oriented discussion I'll be happy to move it.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Steam may be trying to use a Windows-specific font, and ending up with an italicized local replacement by accident. Try installing the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package to see if that helps.

Comment: Already have that installed.  I also tried moving some fonts over from my windows partition after seeing that suggestion in a blog post to no avail.